# Date validation in ASP.NET MVC with DataAnnotations in ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, unobtrusive-validation

I have a DateTime property in my page's ViewModel. I would like to know if there is a built-in way of checking that the user entered a valid date.

Here is what my current code looks like and as of now it is not automatically making sure the user enters a valid date (there is only required validation):

**ViewModel property:**

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime MyDate{ get; set; }
```

**Razor MVC6 view:**

```
<label asp-for="MyDate" class="control-label"></label>
<input asp-for="MyDate" class="form-control" />
<span asp-validation-for="MyDate" class="text-danger" />
```

Comment: What do you mean by _not automatically making sure the user enters a valid date_? What is invalid: the format or is it out of range? What input are you entering and what happens then? What do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you make the `DateTime` nullable in your view model, this will work as you expect:

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime? MyDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: Does that work when applied on a string type ? (to ensure string has valid Date format)

Answer (score 4):

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> MyDate { get; set; }
```

should work

Comment: same as what @RJCuthbertson said just a different way to write it